# Clicking near the target element using mouse co-ordinates inside Firefox Window

Tags: selenium, webdriver

**http://www.dropmocks.com/mFuqje. In the screenshot you can see times like 12am, 1am.I have stored the times in a list and iterated one by one. For every element, I want to perform a click action towards the left(marked green in screenshot) of the target element. I am using Selenium 2.40.0 with Firefox 28.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.5. What is the best way to do this**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActionBuilder.

driver.action.moveToElement(element, xOffset, yOffset).click().perform()

More examples if you need them:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html